# 2 pages in frames: data, form, update data on form submission

Tags: javascript, php, json, forms, refresh

I have a framed page, on the right `src="data.php"` on the left `src="form.php"`

data.php:

```
echo "<a font color=".$row['state'].">state</a>";
```

form.php:

```
<form action="todb.php" method="post">
Active:
 Yes<input type="radio" name="state" value="green">
 No<input type="radio" name="state" value="red">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

the file data.php puts the data on the data base, so I need to visualize the change at the moment of submission, I mean to see change of color of "state" from red to green or the other way around as soon as I click submit.

Any ideas?

**Adding info, just in case:**
index page:

```
<frameset cols="50%,*" border="0" scrolling="no">
<frame name="data" scrolling="auto" src="data.php">
<frame name="form" scrolling="no" src="form.php">
</frameset>
```

Comment: and you want to do it in 1 page 2 frames? cause right now you seem to accomplish that in same frame.

Comment: I don't know if I get you, but on the right frame is data, which need to be updated the moment the form of the left frame is submited, so you still have form on the left and data on the right...

Comment: please make it clear what you are trying to do, what do you expect to get as a result, and what you get instead.

Comment: index page:
`    <frameset cols="50%,*" border="0" scrolling="no">
    <frame name="data" scrolling="auto" src="data.php">
    <frame name="form" scrolling="no" src="form.php">
    </frameset>` does this make it clearer?

Comment: no this is just code, it doesn't tell me where you expect to see state change.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46846/discussion-between-volkan-ulukut-and-andres-chandia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution I was looking for....

at the index.php file I add an id to the frame where I wanted to refresh, this way:

```
<frameset cols="50%,*" border="0" scrolling="no">
<frame name="data" scrolling="auto" src="" id="data-frame">
<frame name="form" scrolling="auto" src="">
</frameset>
```

then a java script at the end of the file that receives the data to send it to the database "todb.php"

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
parent.document.getElementById("data-frame").contentWindow.location.reload();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and that did it.....

Answer (score 0):

change the form's target to left iframe's name

```
<form action="data.php" method="post" target="my_iframe">
Active:
 Yes<input type="radio" name="state" value="green">
 No<input type="radio" name="state" value="red">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<!-- when the form is submitted, the server response will appear in this iframe -->
<iframe name="my_iframe" src="data.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: Is not the solution because that would reload the entire page, and I have data on that page that is not being updated, so data page need to be refreshed on form submition some other way

Comment: did you try it? obviously you didn't cause this will only reload the iframe named 'my_iframe', in your case 'data'.

Comment: anyway please post the data on your other iframe so we can find a solution. if you want to update a specific text, from one iframe to another. javascript can do that.

Comment: index page:
`    <frameset cols="50%,*" border="0" scrolling="no">
    <frame name="data" scrolling="auto" src="data.php">
    <frame name="form" scrolling="no" src="form.php">
    </frameset>` does this make it clearer?